# Trying to format column with another column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, json-formatting

I have a "Completion Date" column and a "Current Step" Column in a list. I am trying to format this "Completion Date" Column so that when the "Current Step" is set to either "Complete" or "Canceled" the "Completion Date" will highlight red and state "Date Needed" if it is empty, and if it is not empty and has a date the column will highlight green. I have no experience with JSON and I tried frankensteining some code together, but it just hasn't been working. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the internal names of your Current Step column is `CurrentStep`, you can apply a column format to the Completion Date column (Column menu > Column settings > Format this column -> Advanced Mode) using this format:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if(length(@currentField) != 1 && ([$CurrentStep] == 'Complete' || [$CurrentStep] == 'Canceled'), 'Date Needed', toLocaleDateString(@currentField))",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if([$CurrentStep] == 'Complete' || [$CurrentStep] == 'Canceled', if(length(@currentField) != 1, 'ms-fontColor-white ms-bgColor-red', 'ms-fontColor-green'), '')"
  }
}
```

I used the `ms-fontColor-*` classes for the colors. If you'd rather highlight the background you could use `ms-bgColor-*` instead (though I'd suggest combining it with `ms-fontColor-white` in that case). Alternatively, you could set the color and/or background-color directly using `style` and swapping out the values in the class expression below to either named colors, hex code, or even rgb.

Here's what it looks like *(Date provided every other row)*:

[image]

---

Edit: Updated the format to use a red background (with white font) when Date is needed.

Comment: Thank you! that works, however how can I make it so the date needed cells are shaded red? I tried adding the "sp-css-backgroundColor-Red" to the attributes section, but I couldn't figure out how to add it in the shade the cell as nothing was happening.

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution. If that doesn't meet your needs, just let me know. Good luck!

Comment: That's perfect, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Please use the below JSON code:**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if((Number([$CompletionDate])==0 && ([$CurrentStep]=='Complete' || [$CurrentStep]=='Canceled')),'Date Needed',toLocaleDateString([$CompletionDate]))",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if(([$CurrentStep]=='Complete' || [$CurrentStep]=='Canceled'),if(Number([$CompletionDate])==0,'Red','Green'),'')"
  }
}
```

[image]